# Is there a way to manipulate Domain object after the validation is completed in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to manipulate Domain object after the validation is completed  in Grails ?

I have to encode the password before inserting to database, but i want to do it only after the validation is completed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, what you validate in your gorm object should be what you save.  If you want to validate an unencoded password then I suggest you create a [command object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) with suitable constraints on the password and validate that.  If the command object passes validation, encode the password and add it to the gorm object you want to insert/update.

This way the gorm object only ever sees encoded passwords and here you should just validate that is not empty (or looks like a hex encoded password).

Comment: Yeah i think you are right, even though i hacked it somehow during insert, it is failing in update.  

Sort of painful, doing this at multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

You can use events:

```
beforeInsert - Executed before an object is initially persisted to the database
beforeUpdate - Executed before an object is updated
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html

You can have a look at the user class generated by the spring security plugin to see an example. Maybe the plugin fits your requirements so that you don't have to reimplement this functionality anyway?

Comment: Nicholas thank you for responding, but beforeInsert and beforeUpdate are called before the beforeValidate method, so i cannot do any changes there.

I need something like afterValidate event.

Comment: I can't find it in the docs but all the other info I've seen on beforeInsert says that it is called after validation.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes Gregg i did, and i see that beforeValidate is getting executed after beforeInsert

Answer (score 0):

Does the job:

```
class User {

  transient saltSource
  transient springSecurityService
  String password

  static constraints = {
    password blank: false
  }
  static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
  }
  def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
  }
  def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
  }
  protected void encodePassword() {
    if (springSecurityService)
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password,saltSource.systemWideSalt)
  }

}
```

Things to consider is how you validate password complexity, should it happen in the service which is in the middle between controller and domain class or should it be custom password field validator.

Comment: I tried the custom field validator, and it doesnt work - the validator is called twice, once when you call user.save, and again before Update with the encoded password which fails the falidation and the save()  fails silently (no errors)

Comment: @JohnLittle in my snippet you might see that I check if `password` is `dirty` in `beforeUpdate` hook, this avoids encoding encoded password. And not sure what `fails silently` means, do you expect exception or error message, without seeing your code its hard to understand, but feels like custom validator issue.